# how to create relative path in hyperlink excel ? (Word.Document.12)

Tags: vba, excel

I have two documents, one which has all the info and it is a word document, and another that is an excel document, that have just some highlights from the word document.

I want to create some links between some selected text in word and excel cells, so far the special past is doing a great job, and create link in this format

```
=Word.Document.12|'C:\Users\...\xxx.docx'!'!OLE_LINK9'
```

Now i want to copy both documents in my usb and past them in other computers, this where the problem is, i would have to do the special past all over again since the path is different now, what i though as a solution was to put the path to the word document in cell let say A1 and concatenate the formula above, something like

```
=Word.Document.12|A1!'!OLE_LINK9'
```

but it doesnt work, it throws an error message, can you please help me?

PS : I would like to avoid vba if possible

Comment: Have you tried copying the files and then checking the links? In the past, such links between Excel workbooks stored the links as relative paths. So if both files start in the same folder you simply copy both to a new folder and the links are pointing to the new folder.

Comment: Yes i did, but it didnt work, it gave me some #REF error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PS : I would like to avoid vba if possible

I have included both ways to do it since the question is tagged with `Excel-VBA` as well :)

Take your pick.

**VBA Way**

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim objOle As OLEObject

    '~~> Change this to the respective Sheet name
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        '~~> This is your embedded word object
        Set objOle = .OLEObjects("Object 1")

        '~~> Cell A1 has a path like C:\Temp\
        objOle.SourceName = "Word.Document.12|" & .Range("A1").Value & "xxx.docx!'"
    End With
End Sub
```

**Non VBA Way**

Create a named range and call it say `Filepath`. Set the formula to

`="Word.Document.12|'" & Sheet1!$A$1 & "xxx.docx'!'"`

Where Cell `A1` will have the file path.

[image]

Next Select your word document and in the formula bar, type `=Filepath` and you are done.

[image]